# Excluding unused Svelte components from any given request's bundle

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

The following question is specific to [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev).

I have a page that could potentially render a subset of various components based upon what the server determines from the request. But since the server is already going to determine what should/should not be displayed, I don't want to include any of the other components in the final bundle shipped to the client since the client will never need that code for that specific request.

To illustrate, in the example code below, if there is no error, I don't want the code for `ErrorToast` included in the bundle.

```html
<main>
    {#if error}
        <ErrorToast {message} />
    {/if}

    {#if hasImages}
        <ImageGallery {images} />
    {/if}

    {#if showUsage}
        <UsageChart {data} />
    {/if}
</main>
```

Is there any way of doing this with SvelteKit?

I attempted dynamic imports (using `await import("$lib/path/to/Component.svelte")`), but that resulted in *only* client side rendering with no SSR (definitely not ok). I also attempted to pass the component to the page from the corresponding endpoint via props, but that seemed to automatically import as a [Server-side component](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-server-side-component-api).

Comment: Have you ever looked upon `<svelte:component>`? This might help you get where you want. https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-component

Comment: Yep! It's definitely one piece of the puzzle. It doesn't solve excluding it from the bundle, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Rich Harris via Twitter](https://twitter.com/Rich_Harris/status/1504626155646767106):

> your bundler can't know that  won't be used, because it can't know that `error` won't change at runtime. closest you can get is this sort of thing:

```js
<script context="module">
    export async function load() {
        const { error, hasImages, showUsage } = get_props_somehow();

        if (error) {
            return {
                props: {
                    component: (await import('./ErrorToast.svelte')).default,
                    props: message
                }
            }
        }

        if (hasImages) {
            // ...
        }

        if (showUsage) {
            // ...
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    export let component;
    export let props;
</script>

<svelte:component this={component} {...props}/>
```